# Unset an env variable on a makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that runs some other make target by first setting some variables:

```
make -C somedir/ LE_VAR=/some/other/stuff LE_ANOTHER_VAR=/and/so/on
```

Now I need to unset **LE_VAR** (really unset, not just override the value with "").

Is there any way to do it so on *GNU Make 3.81*?

Thanks!

Comment: You're allowed to alter the second makefile, but not the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for your replies, this was quite tricky.

When executing make, and setting vars in the parameters, like:

```
make -C le/path install ONEVAR=one OTHERVAR=two
```

We have both ONEVAR and OTHERVAR on the env and the subtasks ran by the first command. This kind of puzzled me because I added to the task (at le/path) to execute a simple bash script that only did:

```
echo $ONEVAR
unset ONEVAR
```

And by my surprise the var $ONEVAR was actually "one" (so it was on the env) and the unset actually cleared it. But, adding an "echo $(ONEVAR)" on the makefile still outputs "one".. This is due to MAKEOVERRIDES, and in fact, as suggested by [Communicating Options to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html):

> The command line variable definitions really appear in the variable
>   MAKEOVERRIDES, and MAKEFLAGS contains a reference to this variable. If
>   you do want to pass flags down normally, but don't want to pass down
>   the command line variable definitions, you can reset MAKEOVERRIDES to
>   empty, like this:
>        MAKEOVERRIDES =

Or as MadScientist suggested above :)

But this was not enough, since this var was still being passed to the other subtasks below (in this situation some nodejs modules that were being compiled on a local folder, and by bad luck, both a js file from phantomjs and some other makefiles where using a var with the same name (e.g., $ONEVAR).

> unexport variable Tell make whether or not to export a particular
>   variable to child processes.
>   [GNU Make Appendix A Quick Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Quick-Reference.html)

What I did was:

```
DESTDIR_BUFFER=$(DESTDIR)
MAKEOVERRIDES := $(filter-out DESTDIR=%,$(MAKEOVERRIDES))
unexport DESTDIR
```

And only then make npm install.

At the end of this task I export DESTDIR with the value at DESTDIR_BUFFER and all the other consequent tasks still work.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your makefile contains something like this to invoke a sub-make:

```
submake:
         $(MAKE)
```

You need to modify the magical variable `MAKEOVERRIDES`, like this:

```
MAKEOVERRIDES := $(filter-out LE_VAR=%,$(MAKEOVERRIDES))
unexport LE_VAR

submake:
        $(MAKE)
```

Comment: still doesn't work.. is it a var passed as an argument to make really an env variable, or has it another kind of handling?

Comment: Oh I get it; you're running a sub-make and you want to remove that variable assignment from the command line when you invoke the sub-make.  I thought you wanted to remove this variable from the environment.  Variables on the make command line are not environment variables, they're make variables.

Comment: Yes.. i've made a wrapper script that did an 'unset' but still not working :S The real problem is that I have a sub node_module that uses a var with the same name..

Comment: You can leave out the "unexport" above, if your sub-makefile uses normal assignment; that will take precedence over anything in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out `unexport variable`. 
From gnu manual

`export variable`

`export variable-assignment`

`unexport variable`

`Tell make whether or not to export a particular variable to child processes`

Refer https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Quick-Reference.html